# parse.com how can I change the createdAt date via the dashboard

Tags: parse-platform

I have a data class.

As an object is added to the class the createdAt date is generated.

I want to change this date manually via the dashboard.  However, when I select the createdAt column for a particular row, it doesn't seem to be editable.  Is there some way of making this column editable ?

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. See: https://www.parse.com/docs/data#data-browser:

*Data Browser*

*The Data Browser is the web UI where you can update and create objects in each of your apps. Here, you can see the raw JSON values that are saved that represents each object in your class.*

[...]

*When using the interface, keep in mind the following:*

[..]

- *The objectId, createdAt, updatedAt fields cannot be edited (these are set automatically).*

[..]*